# linux kernel memory management: ZONE_DMA ,ZONE_NORMAL size changing

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, device

Any fixed ratio for allocating memory zones in linux kernel like ZONE_DMA should be with in 0-16MB, ZONE_NORMAL comes within 16 - 896 MB or we can change according to our demand, if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Those memory zones are defined based on hardware limitations. Even if recompile the kernel with a larger ZONE_DMA then devices which do 16-bit DMA will just fail. Same for DMA32 on 64bit.

In theory perhaps you could shrink some of the zones, but I'm not sure you have a reason for it. AFAIK normal allocations can automatically overflow into the DMA zone.

If you want more than 1G kernel memory then you need to change some top-level config options, not sure which.